# how to make a Table as footer in reportlab

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

I want to make a table as footer with report lab,
the table is already maked , the pages number too.

```
def footer(canvas, doc):
footer_bottom = doc.bottomMargin
canvas.saveState()
canvas.setFont('Helvetica',9)
text = "Page %d" % doc.page
canvas.drawString(inch, footer_bottom, text)
canvas.restoreState()

frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height,)
template = PageTemplate(id='footer', frames=frame, onPage=footer)
 doc.addPageTemplates([template])
```

Any one have idea??

Answer (score 0):

```
def myLaterPages(canvas, doc):
try:
    tab = table()
    cadre = cadre_footer()
    width, height = A4
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman', 9)
    canvas.drawString(2 * cm, 2 * cm, "Page %d " % (doc.page))
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman', 14)
    # canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH / 2.0, PAGE_HEIGHT - 108, Title)
    canvas.restoreState()
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman', 9)
    canvas.drawRightString(10 * cm, 2 * cm, date)
    tab.wrapOn(canvas, width, height)
    tab.drawOn(canvas, 19.6 * cm, 1 * cm)
    cadre.wrapOn(canvas, width, height)
    cadre.drawOn(canvas, 1.3 * cm, 0.9 * cm)
except:
    pass
```

that's working for me, for the first pages the same code